# Perform a Tukey HSD test in the gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary, tukey, kruskal-wallis

I need to perform the analyse of data that have 4 timepoints. I am using R and want to use the gtsummary package. I would like to perform the tukeyHSD to compare the means of each the timepoints for all the continuous data. I know that this test would have to be implemented via the 'add_stat' function. Unfortunately, I am quite new to R and my function writing is not very good. could anyone help me with writing a tukey HSD function that I can implement in the gtsummary package?

I gave attempted the a tukeyHSD function with no luck.